# Data has refreshed to initial state when using Blockui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, blockui

Hi I am using Blockui for stop interacting user from the datatable when user click the check box. i checked the data from database and decide whether need to check or uncheck the checkbox . it take some time to interact with DB for that purpose i am using block ui . but the problem is for example initially first row and second row checkbox is unchecked , when user clicks first row , it checked the checkbox , after that if user click second row check box , it uncheck the first row and check the second row check box. It is happening only when i am using block ui. Can you please help me on this. Posted only the required code.

```
{
                name: 'Verified',
                label: 'Verified',
                options: {
                    filter: false,
                    sort: true,
                    display: true,
                    customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
                      console.log(value);
                      
                        return (
                            
                            <Checkbox
                                value={value}
                                checked={value}
                               {
                                onChange={(event) => {
                                    handleValidate(event, value, tableMeta, updateValue)
                                }}
                            />
                        )
                    }
                }

const handleValidate = (event, one, two, three) => {
            this.setState({blocking:true}) //if i remove the code , it working as expected
            event.preventDefault()
            let id = two.rowData[0]
            let isVerified = !one
            console.log(isVerified);

            fetch(`${projectVerify}/${id}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: areWeDev ? 'omit' : 'include',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    isVerified: isVerified ? 1 : 0
                })
            })
                .then((res) => {
                    return res.json()
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    
                    if (res.ack && res.ack === true) {
                            

                            if(res.id.isVerified==1)
                            {
                                this.setState({blocking:false}) //if i remove the code , it working as expected
                            
                                three(true);

                            }
                            else{
                                this.setState({blocking:false}) //if i remove the code , it working as expected
                                three(false);
                            }
                    }
                        
                        
                    }
                )
                .catch((e) => {
                    this.setState({blocking:false})
                    console.warn('Error sending data', e)
                })
        }
         

<>
                    <BlockUi blocking={this.state.blocking} message={this.state.message} keepInView >
                    <DataTable columns={returnColumns()} title={title} options={options} data={data} />
                    </BlockUi>
```